# Issue with dictionary being defined as "type"

Tags: python, dictionary

Currently, I am working on a historical sim game and I have started using `txt` files.

Unfortunately, my current program is not defining the dictionary and is not running the `__init__` function.

```
nation = {
### Key : [Strength,Speed,Intelligence,Magic,Cosmic] ###
'Castile':[21,21.26,"De Tratsamana","Madrid",""],
'Aragon':[17,24.18,"De Tratsamana","Valencia",""],
'Portugal':[14,12.84,"De Avis","Lisbon",""],
'France':[27,20.75,"Valois","Paris",""],
'England':[27,31.42,"Lancaster","London",""],
'Austria':[15,16.48,"Hapsburg","Wien",""],
'Ottomans':[26,28.65,"Osmanoglu","Constantine",""],
'Venice':[15,16.79,"Elected position","Venezia",""],
'Poland':[18,14.87,"Jagellion","Krakow",""]
          }
#Placing the vaiables into a text file
myfile = open('nation.txt','w')
myfile.write('Castile' + '\n')
nationinfo1 = str(nation['Castile'])
myfile.write(nationinfo1 + '\n')
myfile.write('Aragon' + '\n')
nationinfo2 = str(nation['Aragon'])
myfile.write(nationinfo2 + '\n')
myfile.write('Portugal' + '\n')
nationinfo3 = str(nation['Portugal'])
myfile.write(nationinfo3 + '\n')
myfile.write('France' + '\n')
nationinfo1 = str(nation['France'])
myfile.write(nationinfo1 + '\n')
myfile.write('England' + '\n')
nationinfo2 = str(nation['England'])
myfile.write(nationinfo2 + '\n')
myfile.write('Austria' + '\n')
nationinfo3 = str(nation['Austria'])
myfile.write(nationinfo3 + '\n')
myfile.write('Ottomans' + '\n')
nationinfo1 = str(nation['Ottomans'])
myfile.write(nationinfo1 + '\n')
myfile.write('Venice' + '\n')
nationinfo2 = str(nation['Venice'])
myfile.write(nationinfo2 + '\n')
myfile.write('Poland' + '\n')
nationinfo3 = str(nation['Poland'])
myfile.write(nationinfo3 + '\n')
myfile.close()

class nation():       
     def __init__(r1,nation):
          #Hero's nation is the key ie. Iron Man or Thor
          r1.nation = input("Please enter nation the name of the Nation")
          #attributes are the items in the dictionary
          r1.army = nation[r1.nation][0]
          r1.money = nation[r1.nation][1]
          r1.dynasty = nation[r1.nation][2]
          r1.capital = nation[r1.nation][3]
          r1.marries = nation
          #prints all nation information
          print('nation :',r1.nation,'\nArmy Size:',r1.army,'\nDucat Treasury:',r1.money,'\nDynasty :',r1.dynasty ,'\nCapital :',r1.capital,)
```

Comment: You have a variable named `nation` and a class named `nation`. Do you see how that could be a problem?

Comment: Do you ever call `nation()` after you define the class? Also note that since both the class and the dictionary ate called nation, you lose access to the dictionary

Comment: Change the dict name "nation" or the class object "nation". If you try to call the class or a method of the class, i'd imagine you'd get a type error because it could try to call the variable, which is not possible in Python leading to a type error.

Comment: Also, the convention in Python is to use `self` to refer to the current instance, using `r1` instead is just confusing.

Comment: Capitalize the class nation to `Nation()`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an uncommon problem for beginners: trying to create new functionality using only what you know and can guess from documentation that is not always written with beginners in mind can be difficult. Unfortunately it's the kind of problem that experienced programmers tend to leave behind, so some comments might seem unhelpfully terse. There are, as indicated in the comments, some problems with your naming which I will try to help sort out as I proceed.

I divine from your code that you would like to create `Nation` objects (I capitalised the name because it's common in Python to indicate class names that way), each of which has attributes referred to in comments as Strength, Speed, Intelligence, Magic and Cosmic but in the code as `army`, `money`, `dynasty` and `capital`. I was unable to deduce quite what Cosmic and `married` were supposed to be doing, so I can only hope that what follows is sufficiently explanatory to let you sort that out for yourself if I am wrong.

I hope you can already see that it's confusing to have different names for the same thing. It's even more confusing to have the same name for different things, but as a beginner I understand it can be difficult to hold enough in your head to understand exactly which name refers to what object. If it's any consolation my brother, who is a mathematician way beyond my abilities, is currently having similar issues as he learns Python. But, with that in mind, the name `nation` certainly does seem a bit over-worked in your code.

It isn't usual for a class to initialise itself using interactive input, and you will probably accept that it's not a good idea to write programs that operate like that. Since you are trying to write out each nation's details, I assume that you want to create an object for each nation, and print out its details to the file. If this is wrong then I'm sorry - next time, include a description of what you were hoping for in the question ;-)

Let's start with the data, whose name you will see I have changed to reflect the fact that it holds all the nation data:

```
nation_data = {
    ### Key : [Strength,Speed,Intelligence,Magic,Cosmic] ###
    'Castile':[21,21.26,"De Tratsamana","Madrid",""],
    'Aragon':[17,24.18,"De Tratsamana","Valencia",""],
    'Portugal':[14,12.84,"De Avis","Lisbon",""],
    'France':[27,20.75,"Valois","Paris",""],
    'England':[27,31.42,"Lancaster","London",""],
    'Austria':[15,16.48,"Hapsburg","Wien",""],
    'Ottomans':[26,28.65,"Osmanoglu","Constantine",""],
    'Venice':[15,16.79,"Elected position","Venezia",""],
    'Poland':[18,14.87,"Jagellion","Krakow",""]
}
```

It's quite simple to loop across all the keys in the dictionary (though you can't assume they'll occur in any particular order) as follows. In this loop I just print out the strength and the capital:

```
for nation_name in nation_data:
    nation = nation_data[nation_name]
    print(nation_name, nation[0], nation[3])
```

On my system this prints

```
Castile 21 Madrid
Aragon 17 Valencia
Portugal 14 Lisbon
France 27 Paris
England 27 London
Austria 15 Wien
Ottomans 26 Constantine
Venice 15 Venezia
Poland 18 Krakow
```

but I can't guarantee that the order will be the same for you. I'm sure we *can* agree, however, that terms like `nation[0]` don't really help the reader to understand what data are being used. One of the *really* nice things about classes is that they let you refer to an object's data (often called *attributes*) by name.

So the next question is how to convert each item in your list to an object. Here I'm going to assume that, since I have demonstrated how to generate all the nation_names there is no need in the class's `__init__` method to perform any input, since the nation name can be a parameter to the method. In fact this is a very common Python idiom: pass a bunch of arguments when calling the class so the `__init__` method can store them as instance attributes. In your particular case this would make the class look something like what follows.
You will observe that the class has only two methods. The `__str__` method of an object is called when you ask for its string value. I gave the `married` parameter to `__init__` a default value, so you don't have to provide a value when you create a new Nation if you don't want.

```
class Nation:
    "Represent what's important about a nation."
    def __init__(self, name, army, money, dynasty, capital, married=""):
        "Initialise the instance attributes."
        self.name = name
        self.army = army
        self.money = money
        self.dynasty = dynasty
        self.capital = capital
        self.married = married
    def __str__(self):
        return "Nation: {}: Army: {}; Money: {}; Dynasty: {}; Capital: {}; Married: {}".format(
                self.name, self.army, self.money, self.dynasty, self.capital, self.married)
```

I can now create a nation and print it. You should find that this code

```
n1 = Nation("Bitgravia", 20, 200, "Tang", "Information City")
print(n1)
```

prints

```
Nation: Bitgravia: Army: 20; Money: 200; Dynasty: Tang; Capital: Information City; Married:
```

Knowing all this, it's a very simple task to create a `Nation` instance. To store these in a dict called `nations` (which seems a reasonable name because it stores Nation objects) you could write:

```
nations = {}
for name, data in nation_data.items():
    nations[name] = Nation(name, data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4])
```

In fact the developers of Python anticipated the need to pass each member of a list as a bunch of arguments, so the same code could more compactly be written as

```
nations = {}
for name, data in nation_data.items():
    nations[name] = Nation(name, *data)
```

With either implementation,

```
for nation in nations.values():
    print(nation)
```

renders

```
Nation: Castile: Army: 21; Money: 21.26; Dynasty: De Tratsamana; Capital: Madrid; Married: 
Nation: Aragon: Army: 17; Money: 24.18; Dynasty: De Tratsamana; Capital: Valencia; Married: 
Nation: Portugal: Army: 14; Money: 12.84; Dynasty: De Avis; Capital: Lisbon; Married: 
Nation: France: Army: 27; Money: 20.75; Dynasty: Valois; Capital: Paris; Married: 
Nation: England: Army: 27; Money: 31.42; Dynasty: Lancaster; Capital: London; Married: 
Nation: Austria: Army: 15; Money: 16.48; Dynasty: Hapsburg; Capital: Wien; Married: 
Nation: Ottomans: Army: 26; Money: 28.65; Dynasty: Osmanoglu; Capital: Constantine; Married: 
Nation: Venice: Army: 15; Money: 16.79; Dynasty: Elected position; Capital: Venezia; Married: 
Nation: Poland: Army: 18; Money: 14.87; Dynasty: Jagellion; Capital: Krakow; Married:
```

All that remains, should it be important, is ensuring the cities appear in the required order (build a list of them in the order you want, iterate over that list and use the names to look up the relevant item in `nations`) and writing the data to your file (one way would involve adding a `Nation.write` method that takes a file as a argument and writes `str(self)` to the file followed by a newline).

I hope this helps you to understand what a structured answer to your question would look like. As always I have made choices that others might make differently, but overall this is a fairly "Pythonic" approach to solving your problem.

I later realised I should point out that since the nations contain their names, unless you actually need to look them up by name a list of nations wold serve. so you might also write

```
nations = []
for name, data in nation_data.items():
    nations.append(Nation(name, *data))
```

which would simplify the printing code to

```
for nation in nations:
    print(nation)
```